# Can Yasuo ult an enemy that made himself airborn

Tags: league-of-legends

If champions like Khazix or Aatrox jump, they are technically airborne and Yasuo can ult any airborne enemy's.

So is it possible to ult an Aatrox that is jumping and not knocked up by an allies ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works on actual knock-ups, not jumps. I haven't tested myself, but googling found [this forum thread](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=4114285)

Comment: Disappointing :(. would love to counter a Phant ult XD